# How do I install Remix OS in GNOME Boxes?

Tags: virtual-machine, android, qemu

[Remix OS](http://www.jide.com/en/remixos-for-pc) is an interesting desktopification of Android. It can run off a read-write-able USB stick but it *doesn’t have an installer*. I can boot it up in [GNOME Boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes) just fine, but as I’m just running an ISO file it’s not a persistent read-write system. How do I install from Remix OS’ ISO file onto the hard drive inside Boxes?

Answer (score -1):

I found the following video on their website. 
https://youtu.be/At7_g9ZXu8s?t=25s

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).